# Changing 20 amp breaker to 15 amp

Tags: electrical

I have a 20 amp breaker that feeds 3 lights and 5 outlets. The feed is 12/2 wire, but it changes to 14/2 running to the outlets. Should I replace the 14/2 wire or can I just change the breaker to a 15 amp?

Comment: What are the outlets for?  If just for desk lamp or radio type devices(low wattage) then changing the breaker is the easiest.  If for high wattage devices(toasters, microwaves, hair dryers), then changing the 14 to 12 is the best option.  One or the other must be done, 14 gauge should not be on 20 amp breaker, against code.  Depending on the room location/type, might need to upgrade to 12 gauge anyway for a 20 amp circuit.

Comment: The outlets are in living room so they will power lamps,  vacume, TV, and the like.

Comment: With a normal living room I would go with changing the breaker.

Comment: The breaker you use is determined by the size of the wire in the wall not by what is being connected to that circuit. If you have 14/2 wire then use a 15 amp breaker. If you have 12/2 wire then use 20 amp.

Comment: Either replace the 14/2 wire (and verify there isn't any 14g on the rest of the circuit) or just change the breaker to a 15 amp.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing a renovation why not update the wires to 12 so you can use the 20a breaker?

To answer the question yes you can change the breaker to a 15 amp and be code compliant. I label circuits like this “14 in field” so later someone doesn’t go back and slap a 12 back in.

Comment: Assuming they can replace the 14ga wire easily enough, I'd opt for replacing it with 12ga too. Using a 20a breaker makes it less likely for your vacuum or something to cause a trip while other things are on. Plus make it less likely that the next person in there will go "hey, this is 12ga wire, I can just replace this with a 20a breaker"

Answer (score 0):

No need to replace the cable, strange that it's 14/2  off of 12/2 though. The breaker definitely needs to be replaced with a 15 amp one.  Are all the outlets on 14/2?

Comment: Don't think that the amount of 14/2 matters, just that there is some on the circuit is the deciding factor for the need of a 15 amp breaker.  Might be easier/cheaper to change cable if a small amount in an easy to get at location.

Comment: @crip659 It absolutely doesn't matter how much. I was wondering if maybe some of the outlets were added on later and the DIYer used the 14/2 and didn't replace the breaker.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and suggestions. As I move forward in my renovation I am sure I will have more questions. The house I am rehabbing is 100 yrs. old and it seems that it has been upgraded throughout the years. I will switch out the breaker and then I plan on checking the other 20 amp breakers to see if they jumped off those in a similar fashion.

Comment: Nothing strange about a DIYer putting 14/2 on the end of a circuit that was otherwise 12/2 and is on a 20a breaker. It is _not_ correct, but it's also _not_ strange.